# In MySQL, when I use Limit in a Subquery, it returns nothing?

Tags: mysql, row, limit, inner-join

I'm trying to `INNER JOIN` a single row from a table. The query returns rows until I add the `LIMIT 1` line of code and then it returns nothing and it doesn't make any sense to me. Here is my code.

```
SELECT DISTINCT pd.pid, fv.flow_bmi, fv.flow_date
FROM patient_data pd
INNER JOIN ( ... )
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT pid, flow_bmi, flow_date
  FROM flow_vitals
  ORDER BY flow_date DESC
) fv ON fv.pid = pd.pid

#Results
-------------------------------
 pid  | flow_bmi  | flow_date
-------------------------------
 6073 | 31.90     | 2011-11-06
 6073 | 33.10     | 2011-11-05 <-- I don't want this row returned
 6072 | 32.10     | 2011-08-01
```

And now when I add `LIMIT 1`

```
SELECT DISTINCT pd.pid, fv.flow_bmi, fv.flow_date
FROM patient_data pd
INNER JOIN ( ... )
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT pid, flow_bmi, flow_date
  FROM flow_vitals
  ORDER BY flow_date DESC
  LIMIT 1
) fv ON fv.pid = pd.pid

#Expected Outcome
-------------------------------
 pid  | flow_bmi  | flow_date
-------------------------------
 6073 | 31.90     | 2011-11-06
 6072 | 32.10     | 2011-08-01

#Actual Outcome
-------------------------------
 pid  | flow_bmi  | flow_date
-------------------------------
 No rows returned.
```

I don't know why `LIMIT` breaks this, and what I really want is an `INNER JOIN` that returns only one row based on the latest date. It seems like there are a ton of questions on this same topic but they end up using `MAX()` or `LIMIT` which both have not worked for me.

Comment: What's the result of just the inner query with the `LIMIT 1`?

Comment: @VinodVishwanath - `pid:6073|flow_bmi:31.90|flow_date:2011-11-06` is what gets returned when I only run the inner query.

Comment: Can't think of any reason why LIMIT 1 should break the query, but a couple questions/suggestions:
1. What's the function of the first `INNER JOIN(...)`? What's the `ON` clause for that join? 
2. A subquery needn't have an ORDER BY or LIMIT clause, they might as well be applied on the outer query to filter out unwanted results - just makes the execution simpler to understand.

Comment: @VinodVishwanath - Haha yeah I have no reason either. And to answer your question, that `INNER JOIN()` works fine so I just truncated the code and failed to put the `ON` portion in by accident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually want *one row per group*, not *one row total* from the `flow_vitals` table. Putting a `LIMIT 1` there returns just the top row from the entire table.

I assume the row you want is the one with the maximum `flow_date` for that `pid`. Try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pd.pid, fv.flow_bmi, flow_date
FROM patient_data pd
INNER JOIN ( ... )
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT pid, flow_bmi, flow_date
  FROM flow_vitals
) fv ON fv.pid = pd.pid
WHERE flow_date = (SELECT MAX(ffvv.flow_date) FROM flow_vitals ffvv WHERE ffvv.pid = fv.pid)
```

Or, as a join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pd.pid, fv.flow_bmi, flow_date
FROM patient_data pd
INNER JOIN ( ... )
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT pid, flow_bmi, flow_date
  FROM flow_vitals
) fv ON fv.pid = pd.pid
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT pid, MAX(flow_date) AS maxDate
  FROM flow_vitals
  GROUP BY pid
) fvMax ON fv.pid = fvMax.pid AND fv.flow_date = fvMax.maxDate
```

I also wonder if `DISTINCT` is really necessary here.